# Angularjs click outside event not working in child directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, click

I'm trying to create a dropdown list inside of a button - when clicking the button the dropdown list should open. 
I'm trying to get the list hidden with a click outside. The dropdown is actually closing when clicking outside, but it is also closed when clicking on the list - which is not expected. 
How do I keep the list open when clicking inside the list? 
stopPropagation is not a good solution to me since it corrupts the expected flow of the click event.
Appreciate your help.

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/1HousD8KytGept0o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you have created so many directives to handle this task. I have edited 'onClickOutside' directive of your project in order to achieve what you have asked. Please refer to the following example.

```
app.directive('onClickOutside', ['$document', "$parse", function ($document, $parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {

      function isDescendant(parent, child) {
        var node = child.parentNode;
        while (node != null) {
          if (node == parent) {
            return true;
          }
          node = node.parentNode;
        }
        return false;
      }

      var anyOtherClickFunction = $parse(attr["onClickOutside"]);
      var documentClickHandler = function (event) {
        var isChild = element[0] && isDescendant(element[0], event.target);
        var showList = true; 
        if (!isChild) {
          if (element[0] == event.target) showList = true;
          else showList = false; 
        }
        scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.showList = showList;
          });
      };

      $document.on("contextmenu", documentClickHandler);
      $document.on("click", documentClickHandler);
      scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
        $document.off("contextmenu", documentClickHandler);
        $document.off("click", documentClickHandler);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```